# How to setup debugging in Visual Studio Code for React Native?

Tags: android, ios, debugging, react-native, visual-studio-code

I searched but I can't find any external sources except for Visual Studio Code docs, and just following those docs doesn't allow me to debug React Native apps both in iOS and Android.

I keep getting the error message (this one for Android, for iOS, is similar:

> [vscode-react-native] [Warning] Couldn't import script at
> http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false.
> Debugging won't work: Try reloading the JS from inside the app, or
> Reconnect the VS Code debugger: path must be a string

My `launch.json` file as:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Android",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "internalDebuggerPort": 9090,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "iPhone 6s",
            "internalDebuggerPort": 9090,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "internalDebuggerPort": 9090,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "internalDebuggerPort": 9090,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to debug both in the iOS simulator and in an Android device but the process never attaches to the external JS debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very new to React Native - Debugging in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654585/very-new-to-react-native-debugging-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Go to debug option in vscode and select debugging type

- select attach to packager
- run your react native app by

  ```html
      react-native run-android
  ```

  -> shake the phone and select Debugg remote JS option

  Done...

Answer (score -2):

You can use Vscode extension "**React native tools**" for debugging react-native apps.

Comment: I think he is already using that extention