# breakpoints are greyed out vs code react-native-tools debug

Tags: debugging, react-native, react-native-tools

No matter if I choose "Attach to packager" configuration running packager with

> react-native start

first or "Debug Android", breakpoints that I set in vs code are greyed out and are not get hit.

[image: greyed out breakpoint]
Here is information I am getting from Debug Console:

> OS: win32 ia32 Adapter node: v7.9.0 ia32 vscode-chrome-debug-core:
>   3.23.0 Starting debugger app worker. Established a connection with the Proxy (Packager) to the React Native application Debugger worker
>   loaded runtime on port 10029 Running application "EugeneKrApp" with
>   appParams: {"rootTag":71}. **DEV** === true, development-level warning
>   are ON, performance optimizations are OFF index.bundle:19019 Warning:
>   componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next major
>   version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary workaround, you
>   can rename to UNSAFE_componentWill

There is a bunch of warnings down the line like the last one about componentDidMount which I didn't include, they hardly influence debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was due to the fact that 'Debug JS Remotely' was not enabled on the device/emulator.

Please check Tunvir Rahman Tusher answer and comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654585/very-new-to-react-native-debugging-in-visual-studio-code#answer-49992968) question.

Enter 'adb shell input keyevent 82' in the cmd/bash on your dev machine while the app is open on the device/emulator. A dialog box opens on the device/emulator like

[image]

Select 'Debug JS Remotely' and it will work out. You might need to restart the debugger.