# React Native app using VSCode - why can't I see any console.logs?

Tags: react-native, logging, visual-studio-code

```
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
      console.log('Hi from React Native')


      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Text>
          {`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
        </Text>
        }         
    />
```

That's my function example of where I'm doing a console.log, but there's nothing showing up in the "Debug Console" of VSCode. I know everything is running and the component likely did mount as I am able to view my app on the Expo client app on my device. I am getting an error saying 'identified expected'.

I'm also not sure what a keyExtractor is doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you cannot use a `console.log` statement there, `FlatList` expects a list of props in that place. You may place your `log` statement in JavaScript code block.

Secondly, to use VSCode's debugger, you have to attach it to your packager first. Have you done that? You'll need a relevant VSCode extension. There's some help available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654585/very-new-to-react-native-debugging-in-visual-studio-code) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native) on how to do that; it's a separate issue. You can simply use Google Chrome as an alternative by enabling JS debugging from your app. (In your app, open the developer menu, then tap `Debug JS Remotely`. Then in the Google Chrome window that opens, right click > `Inspect` > `Console`).

Finally, `renderItem` is a `FlatList` prop which renders each individual item in your list. You can use to style or modify each item of your `FlatList`.

Comment: Can you explain keyextractor? If I wanted to output the index as an item in the flatlist, how could I do so?

Comment: Every item in a `FlatList` should have a unique `key` to identify it. `keyExtractor` tells your `FlatList` what that `key` is going to be. For example, if you have a field called `userId` for every item you're displaying, you could do: `keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.userId;` to assign unique keys to every item. And to fetch keys, you do the following: `renderItem={({item}) => <Text onPress={() => console.log(item.key)}>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</Text>}`