# React-Native: An error occured while attaching debugger to the application. Cannot attach to packager

Tags: react-native, vscode-debugger

Problem:
I am new to react-native and when I try to **Run and Debug** using the **Attach to Packager** configuration I get the following error:

```
An error occured while attaching debugger to the application.  Cannot attach to packager.  Are you sure there is a packager and it is runnig in the port 19001?  If your packager is configured to run in another port make sure to add that to the settings.json. (error code 504) (error code 1401)
```

Solutions attempted:

- Attaching "Trace" to settings.json to verify i'm in a react-native project.  Found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1558)
- Adding port, sourceMaps, and outDir to launch.json. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654585/very-new-to-react-native-debugging-in-visual-studio-code)

Here is a screenshot of my settings/what I'm seeing:
[image]

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04